# Why in SSH appears the -T parameter in the Ubuntu documentation but not in the terminal/console?

Tags: command-line, ssh, openssh, github

Having the following OS:

- Linux Ubuntu (18.04 LTS)

when I execute the `ssh` command I got the following:

```
> ssh
usage: ssh [some characters shown] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
```

According with `Github` documentation in the following section:

- [Testing your SSH connection](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/user/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection)

Has the following sentence:

- `$ ssh -T git@hostname`

From above, observe the `-T` parameter, it does not appear in the first output.

It does not appear even in the 'official' documentation about `SSH`:

- [SSH Command](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/command)

But it appears for example in Ubuntu documentation commands:

- [ssh](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ssh.1.html)

Here I am confused because in Ubuntu's documentation appears the `-T` parameter in the *description* section but not in the *synopsis* section. **Question 1**: Why this difference?

BTW in Ubuntu I executed `apt update` and `apt upgrade`

And well when I execute the `$ ssh -T git@hostname` command I don't receive an error about the `-T` parameter is invalid. Therefore it is valid but it does not appear in the first output.

**Question 2:** Why did not fail the command execution if theoretically `-T` is an invalid parameter?

**Question 3**: when is mandatory use `-T`?

**Alpha**

Using the `dpkg -l openssh-client` command shows:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                          Version                     Architecture                Description
+++-=============================================-===========================-===========================-===============================================================================================
ii  openssh-client                                1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3          amd64                       secure shell (SSH) client, for secure access to remote machines
```

For the `ssh -V` command shows:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

Comment: I have never installed manually something about `SSH`. Through `apt list --installed` I only have the `openssh-client` installed, Do you have installed the `openssh-server`? By the moment I don't need remote access to my PCs

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the outputs of `dpkg -l openssh-client` and `ssh -V` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `T` option is in fact mentioned, in the portion of the synopsis that you redacted:

```
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

The usage is described in `man ssh`:

```
 -T      Disable pseudo-terminal allocation.
```

essentially the opposite of `-t`:

```
 -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute
         arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
         very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
         options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

The synopsis shows it like `[some characters shown]` rather than like `[-p port]` because it's one of the (many) options that doesn't take an argument.

Comment: Now I understand why the `[-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy]` part is shown in bold in the man documentation - it in the synospsis section. Well explained the latest paragraph, huge thanks!